# Setting a proxy for pandas_datareader

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, urllib, pandas-datareader

System: Anaconda Python 3.6.4 x64 on Win 7 x64

I am trying to use pandas_datareader.data behind a proxy without being able to modify my Windows PATH.

As far as I understand, pandas_datareader uses urllib.requests to connect to the respective service providers. By default, urllib uses an opener which tries to detect the PATH-proxysettings:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/urllib2.html#proxies

I can replace the opener to force it to use my specified proxy settings, and *as far as I understand*, this modifies the behavior of the urllib on a global level, not just for a given instance.

My assumption is that using install_opener({...}) should modify the behavior of pandas_datareader. However, I don't see a change.

Example:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import urllib

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

# this fails, since no proxy is set
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'morningstar', start, end)

# install proxies to opener
proxies = {'http' : 'http://...', 
           'https': 'https://...'}
proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# this also fails, why?
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'morningstar', start, end)
```

Could anyone please point me to my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

This is how i did it

```
proxies = {'http': 'http:your proxy:8080'}
headers = {     "Accept":"application/json",
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
            "Accept-Encoding":"none",
            "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q = 0.8",
            "Connection":"keep-alive",
            "Referer":"https://cssspritegenerator.com",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, 
             like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
            }

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    s.proxies.update(proxies)

gspc = web.DataReader('^GSPC', 'yahoo', start, end, session=s)
```

Comment: This solution works with : `proxies = {'http': 'http://hostname:8080', 'https': 'https://hostname:8080'}`... and if you have certificate problems (for example with a Burp Proxy) you will need : `s.verfiy=False` added...